# F# interactive terminated

Tags: f#, mono, xamarin.mac, f#-interactive

I just updated Xamarin Studio on my Mac. Xamarin Studio is version 6.2  (build 1821). F# interactive now reports the error:

```
Session termination detected. Press Enter to restart.
```

Pressing ENTER does not restart the shell. I have closed the shell and opened it again with the same result. I have closed Xamarin Studio and restarted the computer.

I deleted Xamarin Studio and downloaded it again from the source. F# interactive still does not open.

Does anyone know how I can restart the shell?

Update: I reinstalled version 6.1.4 and the shell works again. Older versions can be obtained from https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads, after logging in.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.. Pfff its really a pain in the a$$. i know now i should never upgrade immediately a critical software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in the C9SR0 release:

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_6.2/xamarin.studio_6.2/

> Fixed: 52721 - F# interactive doesn't work after update.